# I'm not turning up in Careers searches

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

My CV has been filed for over 2 months, and I have yet to turn up in even one search by an employer. I have two of the most popular tags as favorites, and "Telecommute" is checked. Am I overlooking something obvious?

I've prepared a visual overview of my dilemma:

http://shup.com/Shup/366138/11051715921-File-Your-CV-Stack-Overflow-Careers-Opera.png

---

http://stashbox.org/929878/110517143625-My-CV-Stack-Overflow-Careers-Opera.png

---

http://stashbox.org/929875/11051714357-My-CV-Stack-Overflow-Careers-Opera.png

---

http://stashbox.org/929880/11051714383-My-CV-Stack-Overflow-Careers-Opera.png

---

http://stashbox.org/929873/110517143258-My-CV-Stack-Overflow-Careers-Opera.png

## ???

Comment: Are you really interested in an internship, or did you check that simply in an effort to be noticed?

Comment: I really was interested, maybe now that summer's halfway over I should uncheck it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We looked into this.  It looks like you aren't showing up in many results because of your location and because you're not willing to relocate.

There was also a bug where not being willing to relocate was keeping you from showing up for employers who were willing to relocate you (even if you wouldn't need to relocate).  We've fixed that, so you should show up a bit more now.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Everyone:  We do monitor meta pretty frequently but always remember you can reach us directly at careers@stackoverflow.com with any careers related problems or questions.

Answer (score 3):

Where do you live?

Comment: This probably sums it up. I was hoping telecommute and "willing to relocate" would make my location irrelevant, but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not many companies are looking for telecommuters.  If you don't live in a tech hotbed (even if you check "willing to relocate") then you simply aren't going to get many searches, nevermind job inquiries.  I've been on there for many months, and have only showed up in a handful of searches, and the only two inquiries I've received were shotgun (ie, they obviously impersonally emailed many, many people).

Unfortunately, careers doesn't turn your hometown into a hotbed of technical activity.

Comment: Yes, especially the willing to relocate part. I am an employer, I would not post or search for someone on any single site, rather, I'd use multiple sites to be diligent. I'd rather hire someone and give a 10k signing bonus after 90 days than hire someone and pay 10k immediately for relocation with no bonus. Why? They may not work out. We love telecommuters, but we also like it when they can come in for (yes, really) important meetings, meet clients, etc.